# Load and run external JavaScript file from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP script `register.php`.

Within that file I want to call and run an external JavaScript file, `charge.js`.

The directory structure is

```
public/
  index.php
  register.php
  js/
   charge.js     // I want to move from this ...
src/
  register.php
  js/
    charge.js    // ...to this for security reasons
```

On my Apache webserver `public/` is the ROOT directory.

At the end of `public/register.php` I have the line

`<script src="/js/charge.js"></script>`

which runs `public/js/charge.js` and creates the charge element on the registration form, coded in `public/register.php`.

`src/register.php` contains other code which completes the registration process.

`public/register.php` includes the line

`require **DIR** . '/../src/register.php';)

When I move the line `<script src="/js/charge.js"></script>` to the end of `src/register.php` (intending to call `src/js/charge.js`) nothing happens.

```
<?php
...
require('js/charge.js');
...
?>
```

and

```
<?php
...
?>
<script src="js/charge.js"></script>
<?php
...
?>
```

with no apparent errors, but (e.g.) `console.log()` statements in `charge.js` are not printing to console.

`

Comment: JS is literally a differerent programming language, and will run _in your user's browser, on their computer_, not on your server. By the time JS can even run, PHP has already done its job, and died server-side, with the the page code not anywhere _near_ your server anymore. What would you even expect this to do? As for "no apparent errors": no of course not, you generated the HTML source code for a script element. That's literally what PHP was born to do: generate HTML code =)

Comment: We can't see what is in charge.js, so we don't know what it's likely to do. Provide a [mre] of the issue if you need more help. Thanks

Comment: See this question is closed: will read the referenced FAQ, thanks. I realized I can leave the JS file in `public/js/charge.js` as no sensitive information there; keep an associated PHP file (not mentioned) in `src/` and echo a needed JS variable (return of client secret key from server to client) as an echoed "global" $VAR (https://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/1904943), picked up by `public/charge.js`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. JS is run on the client browser not on the server like PHP. To run JS on the server you have to install a JS interpreter and run the code using that via the php command exec which is used to execute scripts outside of the PHP environment.

Comment: Thank you; I updated my directory structure and question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you want to accomplish there but you can execute a js file with node on server side like this =>

```php
<?php
// register.php
$command = "node charge.js";
$output = exec($command);
echo $output; // Output from the JavaScript execution
?>
```